# Understanding why $\nabla_i\nabla^j\nabla_jA^i = \nabla^j\nabla_i\nabla_jA^i - R_i^s\nabla_sA^i +R_s^j\nabla_jA^s $

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity, gauge-theory

I know that generaly we can define the Riemann curvature tensor as:

$$\nabla_a\nabla_dV^b -\nabla_d\nabla_aV^b = - {R_{adi}}^bV^i$$

Consider the equation
$$\nabla^j\nabla_jA^i = \frac{4\pi}{c}J^i \space \space \space\space\space\space (1)$$

If we then apply $\nabla_i$ on (1) and apply the continuity equation $\nabla_iJ^i = 0$ as well as the lorenz gauge $\nabla_iA^i = 0$ we can deduce the identity

$$\nabla_i\nabla^j\nabla_jA^i = \nabla^j\nabla_i\nabla_jA^i - R_i^s\nabla_sA^i +R_s^j\nabla_jA^s  $$

I am unsure how to deduce this expression though as when I try to apply the equations and identities above I can not get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first term on the RHS has 3 $i$'s. There might be some mistakes here.

Comment: Noted and i have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though defined using vector fields, the Riemann tensor also describes the antisymmetrized second derivatives of tensors of higher order:
$$
(\nabla_i\nabla_j-\nabla_j\nabla_i)T^{kl}=R^k{}_{mij}T^{ml}+R^l{}_{mij}T^{km}
$$
This can be shown a number of ways; one convenient  path is to consder tensors of the form $T=U\otimes V$ for vector fields $U,V$ and extend to the rest by $C^\infty M$-linearity. (Similar formulae exist for tensors of higher order; they can be derived in much the same way.)

Once you have this identity, you can apply it to $(\nabla_i\nabla_j-\nabla_j\nabla_i)\nabla^jA^i$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still don't understand how to deduce that $(\nabla_i\nabla_j-\nabla_j\nabla_i)T^{kl}=R^k{}_{mij}T^{ml}+R^l{}_{mij}T^{km}$. There must be a way to do so using the fact that $\nabla_a\nabla_dV^b -\nabla_d\nabla_aV^b = - {R_{adi}}^bV^i$ but i just don't know to to do so.

Comment: To elaborate on my suggestion, start with the case that $T=U\otimes V$ (i.e. $T^{kl}=U^kV^l$), and use the Leibniz rule:$$\nabla_X(A\otimes B)=\nabla_XA\otimes B+A\otimes \nabla_XB$$ for any tensor fields $A,B$. Then, you can show that the expression depends $C^\infty M$-linearly on $T$, i.e. $$(\nabla_i\nabla_j-\nabla_j\nabla_i)(fT^kl)=f(\nabla_i\nabla_j-\nabla_j\nabla_i)T^{kl}$$Since every $2$-tensor field $T$ is a $C^\infty M$-linear combination of tensor products, the expression always holds.